# Does Google Bookmarks show us how many total bookmarks we have?

Tags: google, bookmarks, google-bookmarks

Does Google Bookmarks show us how many total bookmarks we have?

I've searched high and low for such a basic feature that I think it is really weird that there isn't such a feature!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is no such feature. You cannot directly see how many bookmarks you have, but:

[image]

you can add up the sum of all the **Unlabeled** Bookmarks and the Bookmarks under various different Labels.

Otherwise, you can do as I do: Keep all the Bookmarks as **Unlabeled**, so that the Count of Unlabeled Bookmarks gives you the total number of Bookmarks you have.

Comment: How do you organize your bookmarks then if they are all unlabeled?

Comment: @Pacerier Okay, so label them, and just add the number indicating number of bookmarks each label to get your total number of bookmarks.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you can find out how many bookmarks you have right [here](https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync). https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync

sample: [image]

Comment: This is a different thing. I'm talking about google.com/bookmarks while you are talking about the browser bookmarks.....

Comment: The address @Pacerier is actually chrome://bookmarks/, and they are the same thing that Poppo9000 is referring to. 3 years later, and it's still the same answer.

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe something wrong with my syncing? Its showing there that i have 393 bookmarks, while i have at least 50000 on chrome. Profile is in chrome set up and must be syncing since last installation, but now i see in that link that bookmark number showing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To view how many Chrome bookmarks you have without using Google sync, use this Chrome extension, https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/%C3%BCber-simple-bookmark-coun/mogbbilahcoegijagmcmleheifpijffa .

To use @Poppo9000's answer, you must be syncing your bookmarks with Google.

Answer (score 0):

For Edge, export Favourites and run `$$('a')` to get the count.

[image]